# How to model recurring events in terms of recurring rules to efficiently find them again for a particular day?

Tags: ios, eventkit

I am working for an `iOS App` where I am implementing calendar function as a part. I made my mind not to use `EKEvent` for several reasons. Therefore I need to have my own `Event` class and my own `CalendarController` to display Event graphically. `Event` object are being saved as a single row entry in a SQLite database with start and end dates. Everything is fine, but now I need to model recurring events for both saving and displaying.

What is the best way to save the recurring rules inside the Event object and event database? I am thinking to use `EKRecurrenceRule` class but... how to get all the Events for today (or for a particular day) from the database effectively rather iterating a lot. Can `EKRecurrenceRule` class at least answer the question `When is the next occurrence date?`.

iDevices don't have much power and I need to keep my App responsive too.

Are there any framework given to model the problem efficiently?

I expect mostly **iOS specific** answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be curious to know what reason you have for not using EKEvent, even though you're still willing to use EventKit stuff. You could use a standard EKEvent and just add additional data in your own database (linked by the event's id). Also, why not use Core Data rather than SQLite?

Comment: @jcaron Most of the EKEvent properties are readonly. Yes, you can let the EKEventEditController to create it for you, but the App is having other ecosystem from the beginning for an eg. I must include Documents, Projects, Employees and many more custom elements. As I told you the App is from 2010 and we didn't move to Core Data again for many reasons let's say less programing capacity. Is it possible to give the solution with the Core Data here?